# How to use --split-debug-info=/<project-name>/<directory>

Tags: flutter

In the command below, how to use `--split-debug-info=/<project-name>/<directory>`

```
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/<project-name>/<directory>
```

When I declare project-name &  directory path then the path contains nothing after build.

> The --split-debug-info flag specifies the directory where Flutter can
>   output debug files. This command generates a symbol map.

So the directory defined, but where are the resulted symbol maps?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, make sure you are using a version of **Flutter framework** >= **1.16.2**, you can check it by running:

```
flutter --version
```

And if it's not the case, you can upgrade the **Flutter framework** by running:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Then, in order to generate the symbol map files when you run the `flutter build` command, you can use the command like this:

```
 flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=some_parent_directory/some_child_directory
```

Note that **some_parent_directory** and **some_child_directory** are arbitrary names that you can replace for whatever you want.

Also note that there's **no slash** (/) symbol at the beggining of the right side of the equals (=) symbol of the `--split-debug-info=some_parent_directory/some_child_directory` part of the command.

For the example above, after the command finishes, you can find a **some_parent_directory** directory under your project's root directory, which contains another directory called **some_child_directory** which finally contains the **symbol map** files:

- **app.android-arm.symbols**
- **app.android-arm64.symbols**
- **app.android-x64.symbols**

Answer (score 47):

A reasonable value would be:

```
--split-debug-info=build/app/outputs/symbols
```

This puts it into a logical place near where the actual result files would appear, anyway.

Answer (score 12):

**The ideal directory would be**  : `build/app/outputs/symbols`

**So :**

```
--split-debug-info=build/app/outputs/symbols
```

- 

The /<**directory**> can also be replaced with the **relative path** of the project or **exact location**.

Ex:
`./ProjectFolderName/output`

> It will create ProjectFolderName folder inside your project directory

or

`/Users/apple/Desktop/items/example`

> It will be specific path of folder

Answer (score 1):

**It is recommended if you are going to upload it on Play Store.**

```
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use different targets and flavors, place the flavor last, other way is not obfuscating for some reason

```
flutter build apk -t lib/flavors/company_a/prod.dart --obfuscate --split-debug-info=obfuscate/symbols --flavor=company_a_prod
```

That way is not working for me :

```
flutter build apk -t lib/flavors/company_a/prod.dart --flavor=company_a_prod release --obfuscate --split-debug-info=obfuscate/symbols
```