# flutter build appbundle --obfuscate error

Tags: flutter, apk

I want help configuring the apk file
I see this message

```
> flutter build appbundle --obfuscate

"--obfuscate" can only be used in combination with "--split-debug-info"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use --split-debug-info=/<project-name>/<directory>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61976886/how-to-use-split-debug-info-project-name-directory)

Comment: the solution to your problem may be here [How to obfuscate Flutter apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542764/how-to-obfuscate-flutter-apps)

Comment: error: error reading C:\Users\deuts\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.lifecycle\lifecycle-common-java8\2.4.0-beta01\5b8f86fea035328fc9e8c660773037a3401ce25f\lifecycle-common-java8-2.4.0-beta01.jar; zip END header not found
error: error reading C:\Users\deuts\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.lifecycle\lifecycle-common\2.4.0-beta01\1fdb7349701e9cf2f0a69fc10642b6fef6bb3e12\lifecycle-common-2.4.0-beta01.jar; zip END header not found